# Ways to prove the Zsigmondy's theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How to prove the [Zsigmondy's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) with cyclotomic polynomials?
Is there a proof which does not rely on cyclotomic polynomials? How many ways are there?

Comment: Related: [Elementary proof of Zsigmondy's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660585)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several proofs available for Zsigmondy's theorem: Zsigmondy (1892), Birkhoff and Vandiver (1904), Dickson (1905), Artin (1955), Hering (1974) and Lüneburg (1981).
*All* of them use cyclotomic polynomials (which is natural).
If there is some proof without it, it might be just artificial. 
A reference for a proof is (among many other sources) the article "On Zsigmondy primes" by
M. Roitman (‎1997).