# Infinitely many strong pseudoprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

A composite $n=2^sd+1$ is a strong pseudoprime to base a if n satisfies either $a^d\equiv 1 \pmod n$ or $a^{2^{r}d}\equiv -1 \pmod n$ for some $0\le r\lt s$.

It can be shown that
1.By considering $m=\frac{a^{2p}-1}{a^{2}-1}$, where $p$ is an odd prime not dividing $a^{2}-1$, there are infinitely many Fermat pseudoprimes to base $a$.
2.If $n$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $2$ then $2^{n}-1$ is a strong pseudoprime to base $2$.

With $1$ and $2$, it is deduced that there are infinitely many strong pseudoprimes to base $2$. How can we generalize this to show that there are infinitely many strong pseudoprimes to any given base $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I can try to tweak my original proof to make it correct, but I think it would be more illuminating to prove a stronger statement (which is where my ideas for weaker proofs would come from).

Consider the cyclotomic polynomails evaluated at $a$, $\Phi_n(a)$. We have that $\frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}$ are precisely the primes $p$ such that the multiplicative order $a$ modulo $p$ equals $n$. This is more or less by definition of cyclotomic polynomials, but can be seen for example in the proof given in [Elementary Proof of Zsigmondy's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660585/elementary-proof-of-zsigmondys-theorem).

We have from [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Divisors_of_Cyclotomic_Polynomials) that $\frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}\equiv 1\mod n$. Except for finitely many cases, these are greater than $1$, and thus $\frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}=2^sn+1$.

Now let $n$ be an odd number. We have that $\frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}$ is either prime or a strong pseudoprime, because $a^n\equiv 1\mod \frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}$. (because $\frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}|a^n-1$).

We can see that $\frac{\Phi_n(a)}{\gcd (n,\Phi_n(a))}$ must be infinitely often composite (this is not necessarily obvious, but is explained in more generality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303473/what-can-be-said-about-the-primality-of-zsigmondy-numbers) (sorry I don't know of a better reference)). Thus there are infinitely many strong pseudoprimes to base $a$ (these are even stronger pseudoprimes called overpseudoprimes).

---

There is a slight error in my original proof below:

Let $m_a$ be a composite odd number coprime with $a$. Then $N=\frac{a^{m_a}-1}{a-1}$ is a Strong Pseudoprime base $a$.

We can show this as follows: We have that $N$ is composite because $m_a$ is composite ([Zsigmondy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem)). Then note that the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a$ modulo $p$ is $m_a$. But $m_a$ is odd as given, so $a^{m_a}=1\mod N$ \sout{where $N=2^sm_a+1$, as desired.}

We can do a similar analysis to get the second option ($a^{2^rd}=-1\mod N$).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice!//
May I further clarify the followings
1.By Zsigmondy's theorem, there exists a prime $p$ that divides $a^{m_a}-1$ and does not divide $a^k-1$for k<$m_a$. Is the $p$ in your solution referring to this prime p?\

2.Should we say that the multiplicative order of $a$ divides $m_a$ instead of exactly equals $m_a$?\

3.From the Zsigmondy's theorem, we got the congruence $a^{m_a}\equiv 1 \pmod p$, how can we extend this to $a^{m_a}\equiv 1 \pmod N$?\

4.How can N be expressed as $2^{s} m_a+1$?

Comment: 1. I use Zsigmondy's Theorem to show that $N$ is composite, because $a^d-1$ is a factor of $a^{m_a}-1$ when $d|m_a$. Also the $p$ in my solution is a typo, it should be $a$ modulo $N$, not $a$ modulo $p$; I corrected this now. 2. The multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $p$ divides $m_a$, you are right, but the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $N$ is precisely equal to $m_a$. 3. As explained above, the $p$ was a typo, we immediately get $a^{m_a}=1\mod N$. You can see this as follows: $N|(a^{m_a}-1)/(a-1)\Longrightarrow a^{m_a}-1=0\mod N\Longrightarrow a^{m_a}=1\mod N$.

Comment: Also, since $a^n-1<N$ for $n|m_a$, $n\neq m_a$, we have that $m_a$ is the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $N$. 4. You are right, this is not immediately true; I will edit answer if I have time.